# Spring MVC message not appearing in view when using redirect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am writing a Spring application where new users can be added. The only data that is inputted is a username and password. Two users cannot have the same username and I do check for this (and it works).

If a user is successfully added I return to the main page and want to display the message "New user added". If they are not successfully added I want to stay on the current page and display the message "Username already exists". Currently the scenario for an unsuccessful attempt works. For a successful attempt, the navigation part works but the message does not display.

Here is the relevant code:

UserCredentialsController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserCredentialsController {

    //Omitted some methods above



@RequestMapping(value = "/savenewuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newuser") NewUserValidation newUserValidation, BindingResult result, Model model)
{
 if(result.hasErrors())
 {

     //Return to form with errors displayed (messages in NewUserValidation class)
     return "newuserform";
 }
    else
 {

     //Add new user to database then redirect to main page.
     User user = new User();
     user.setUsername(newUserValidation.getUsername());
     user.setPassword(newUserValidation.getPassword());
     if(userService.addUser(user))
     {
         model.addAttribute("message", "New user added");
         return "redirect:/";
     }
     else
     {
         model.addAttribute("message", "Username already exists");
         return "newuserform";
     }
 }
}

 //Omitted some methods below.
```

newuserform.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix='form' uri='http://www.springframework.org/tags/form'%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New User</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="message">
            <c:if test="${message!=null}">${message}</c:if>
        </div>
        <form:form method="post" action="savenewuser" modelAttribute="newuser">
            <table class="no-border">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h1>Add New User</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-border">
                    <td class="no-border">Username</td>
                    <td class="no-border"><form:input type="text" path="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="no-border">
                    <td class="no-border">Password</td>
                    <td class="no-border"><form:input type="password" path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add New User" /><br />
                    <form:errors path="username" /><br />
                    <form:errors path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

mainpage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/styles.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/javascript/animation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="message"><c:if test="${message!=null}">${message}</c:if></div>
    <c:if test="${myList==null}">myList not available.</c:if><br /> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Random Answer</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${myList}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${entry.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${entry.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${entry.gender}</td>
                    <td>${entry.randomAnswer}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <a href="/addincident">Add New Person</a> &nbsp; <a href="/addnewuser">Add New User</a> &nbsp; <a href="/login">Log in</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in my controller, in the else-block of the inner if-else statement, if the addUser() method returns true (ie it was successful) then I add the relevant message to the model and then redirect to the main page. Otherwise I add a different message and re-load the same page.

As you can see, one key difference between the two paths is that if addUser() returns true, I added 'redirect' in the String of my return statement. The reason that I did this is because on mainpage.jsp I am loading some data from another table onto the page. Simply returning "mainpage" means the data does not load but the message that I want to display is displayed. Using the method I have shown in my controller above, the data is displayed but the message is not displayed. Interestingly, when I use redirect the message I want to display appears as a parameter in the URL but this does not happen when I do not use redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display message after redirect, use [`RedirectAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

Here is an example usage.

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "User added");
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

And access it in your JSP like normal model variable:

```
<c:if test="${not empty message}">
    <c:out value="${message}" />
</c:if>
```

When you add the message to a Model it will not be available after redirect.

Comment: So I should use RedirectedAttributes instead of a Model object and model.addAttribute? Also does this work if you're not using redirect?

Comment: You should use it if you want the attribute available after redirect (which is the case with your message about successful creation). These attributes are stored in a FlashMap. Take a look at the JavaDoc, it explains how it works in more detail: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html

Comment: I asked about using the Model class when no redirect is being used because I'm not using redirect if the creation fails. But I guess I can still use the Model class in this instance.

Comment: Yes in that case just use `Model` to add the message and in cases when you need the attribute after redirect use the `RedirectAttributes`.